# Can I choose my own name in Zion?

Tags: the-matrix, the-animatrix

[Neo](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Trinity) was Keanu Reeve's hacker name in the [Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix_(franchise)) (I think), but if I don't have a cool online persona, do I get to pick my own name once I'm freed from the Matrix, or is it assigned to me somehow?

---

The reason I ask this particular question is because of [Trinity](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Trinity). Trinity is a very unique sounding name, the only possible reference I can think of for that name would be the Holy Trinity in Christianity. So I've always been curious if Trinity chose her name because she was a devout Christian in the Matrix or was it a shot at Christianity on her part or was it completely unrelated and she picked it because as a word, it sounds kind of cool.

I'm not looking for the reasoning behind Trinity's name btw. It was just her name which made me wonder about names for people freed from the Matrix. **I really don't want to discuss anything theological in any way shape or form.**

Comment: I'm happy with the wording of the title. It's pretty clear what you're driving at.

Comment: @Lexible - Because it wasn't relevant to the question, as the edit has made clear.

Comment: @Richard "the only possible reference I can think of for that name" remains after edit, and was specifically the part of the question I was commenting on. Seems a relevant comment, though definitely not an answer.

Comment: @Lexible _I'm not looking for the reasoning behind Trinity's name btw._

Comment: @InguShama Which is why I made a *comment* not an *answer*. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of matrix-born characters who go by different names in Zion than the ones they were using inside the Matrix. Most obvious is **Thomas "*Neo*" Anderson** but there's also **Mr "*Cypher*" Reagan** and **Karl "*Kid*" Popper** from the Animatrix story "[Kid's Story](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Kid's_Story)".

There seems to be no obvious reason why you can't *choose* to go by a different name after you've been freed, but it would appear that most chosen for release are those that are identified as hackers, and hence have a pre-existing...

> ...hacker alias

---

By the same token, there's no special reason to assume that natural-born Zionese aren't able to change their names. We do see evidence that some of them have nicknames (Jason Locke is referred to as "*Deadbolt*" and Tank and Dozer seem unlikely names at best) but there's no real canon either way.

Comment: _Tank and Dozer seem unlikely names at best_. :D I do very much like this answer. Thanks.